# Why JS can't read value property in calculator application?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm making a calculator. Inspector tells me it cannot read the property of `value` at Line 4 of my JS.

I've gone through line by line and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQEYAOPWDzk) from *mmtutus* on YouTube.

I've gone through each line and my code is identical to his.

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
  var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
  var calculate;

  if (op == "add") {
    calculate = a + b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    calculate = a - b;
  } else if (op == "div") {
    calculate = a / b;
  } else if (op == "mul") {
    calculate = a * b;
  }

  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1" /> Value 2:
    <input type="text" id="value2" /> Operator:
    <select>
      <option value="add"> Add </option>
      <option value="min"> Subtract </option>
      <option value="div"> Divide </option>
      <option value="mul"> Multiply </option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
  </form>

  <div id="result"></div>
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Could you help me to find the root of my issue?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#operator")` - you don't have any element with the ID `"operator"` in your HTML.

Comment: `var op = document.querySelector("#value2").value;`

Comment: You need `<select id="operator">`

Comment: @Barmar  did you just watch that youtube video?

Comment: It's at 05:00 in the video

Comment: I think @Barmar is omniscient

Comment: Thank you everyone!   My g/f told me I was too tired to work on this tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not assigned a class- or id-name with 'operator', so it can not find that element.